# Counter based on column value

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a course which has 20 spots. On my SharePoint, I have created a form to sign up for it and now I want the counter for free slots to go down, every time someone creates an item, that registers them for a certain course.

Maybe I could use a formula to extract the number of items in a view I could create for that value or something like that?

Unfortunately I could not find a way to extract that value. Any ideas?

Part of my problem is, that I cannot use Sharepoint Designer, so keep that in mind when proposing solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of items in the view, use **Count** function.

Create/Modify the list view -> expand the **Totals** section -> pick a column and select **Count**.

If you want to get the number of fields that contains a specific value, group items by the field.